# Every eigenvector of $A$ is orthogonal to some eigenvector of $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ have at least two distinct eigenvalues. Why is it that:

For every eigenvector of $A$, there exists an eigenvector of $A^T$ that is orthogonal to it?

I tried to exploit the two facts: $Au = \lambda u$ for some $\lambda$, and $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x, A^T y \rangle$. However, nothing came in mind.

I know that the solution should be really easy. I guess that I'm having a bad day.

Please only drop **hints**.

Comment: Start with $Au=\lambda u$, $A^Tv=\mu v$, $\lambda\ne\mu$ and consider $\langle Au,v\rangle$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

- $A$ and $A^T$ have the same set of eigenvalues.
- Let $x = u$ and let $y$ be an eigenvector for $A^T$ with a distinct eigenvalue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't help with the case in which $A$ has one eigenvalue and one eigenvector.

Comment: The claim isn't true in that case. Consider a $1 \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Oh I misread the question

Comment: Well, your solution is more general, at least if you work over $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this is true for any $n\times n$ matrix with $n\geq 2$, whether or not it has distinct eigenvalues.

One nice approach is to use Schur triangularization. In particular, we can reduce this question to the case in which $A$ is upper triangular.

Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ denote the standard basis of $\Bbb C^n$.
If $A$ is upper triangular, the $e_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$, and $e_n$ is an eigenvector of $A^*$. These vectors are mutually orthogonal.